# Replace functions in package.loaded

Tags: lua, package, lua-table, lua-5.3

How can you replace all the functions for a particular library in `package.loaded` after a `require` call?

I've tried to iterate over the relevant table but the table comes up empty.

```
local aLibrary = require "aLibrary"

for key,value in ipairs(package.loaded.aLibrary) do
    package.loaded.aLibrary[key] = function() end
end
```

Comment: Why do you want or need this?

Comment: @lhf: `aLibrary` is used by other modules, and it assumes that certain resources are available. I need to replace the function calls to `aLibrary` so I can use the other modules even though the resources aren't available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simpler code below should do it (but note the use of `pairs` instead of `ipairs`).

```
local aLibrary = require "aLibrary"

for key in pairs(aLibrary) do
    aLibrary[key] = function() end
end
```

Note that `require` does not return a *copy* of the library table and so the code above affects its *contents* without *replacing* the library table.

In other words, any later call to `require "aLibrary"` will return the table with the new functions. If you don't want that to happen, then you probably need a new table instead of changing its contents.

Answer (score 2):

How about using [pairs](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-pairs) to go through keys instead of only indices?